# How does the expression "мало ли" mean what it does?

Tags: значения

> Don't just swallow anything they throw at you! **Мало ли** какие слухи про нее
> ходят...

I assume the sentence means:

> **You never know** / **Who knows** what kind of (unreliable) gossip may be circling around about it.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around why the adverb "мало / little" coupled with the interrogative particle "ли" gets to have this meaning. Can I interpret it as:

> What kind of gossip may be circling around –  **Do we know even (a) little about it?!**
>
> What kind of gossip may be circling around –  **Just how little do we know about it?!**
>
> What kind of gossip may be circling around –  **We know so little about it, don't we?**

... asking in a rhetorical fashion? I wonder if some verb like "знать" is omitted?

Comment: it's one of those cases, an idiom, where the whole is larger than the sum of its parts

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Hi. If the main idea is "now matter what/how/when/where", I wonder if "мало ли" is close in meaning to, say, "**какие слухи ни ходили бы**" or "**какие слухи ни ходят**"?

Comment: hi, i posted a separate reply

Comment: to your question of the type of sentence **мало ли** is used in, it's not subordinate, it's a self-standing interrogative sentence, whether it's used after a full stop or after other punctuation marks, here's a host of examples from [Corpus of Russian language](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EC%E0%EB%EE+%EB%E8), although it rarely ends with a question mark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мало ли comes from a rhetorical question which assumes answer No (-"Мало ли?" -"Много."). It signifies distrust based on a lot of contradicting information (possibly existing only in speakers imagination).

It this case it means the following:

Out of a lot of gossip which may be circling around, you can't trust any.

Answer (score 9):

**Мало ли** has got at least three meanings

1 **It doesn't matter**, **no matter**

> Что же она ничего не сказала? Ведь должна была сказать!– **Мало ли** что должна.(Why didn't she say anything? She should have said!– It doesn't matter what she should do.

2.**To be on the safe side, just in case, everything can happen**

> Возьми ружье, в лес идешь, **мало ли** что. (Take a rifle,  you are going to the forest, everything can happen)

3.**A lot,different things**

> **Мало ли** о чем говорят. Всему верить нельзя.(People  talk a lot, but you shouldn't believe it.

Comment: Hi. So is it more like: "Don't believe anything. -- **no matter what** kind of gossip ...", with "мало ли" introducing a subordinate clause? And more literally: "Don't believe anything -- that having **little** to do with any gossip circling around"?

Comment: Right,  with говорят it's like this almost always.

Comment: Do you think that "Мало ли какие слухи про нее ходят..." is interchangeable with "**какие слухи ни ходили бы**" or "**какие слухи ни ходят**"?

Comment: No, not quite."whatever gossip can be heard of her"is какие слухи ни ходили бы

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an English expression that's very close in meaning: "**there's no telling** what kind of gossip may be circling about it". Then again, it doesn't quite have the dismissive undertone which is an option with **мало ли**: it may be there but doesn't have to, depending on context.

No verb is omitted from **мало ли**, it qualifies **какие**. (And it can do that with any other interrogative pronoun.)

Comment: Hi. Now I'm terribly confused... because "there's no telling" is similar to "You never know / Who knows", but is quite different from "no matter what kind of". Now I'm not sure which interpretation to go on...

Comment: @Alone-zee I don't think "no matter what kind of" is a good fit. "No matter" expressions aren't complete, self-contained statements; "мало ли" ones are. Other than that, "мало ли" is kind of neutral with respect to whether the impllied multitude should be a cause for concern, or the opposite, a cause for dismissiveness. It works either way. Maybe the common denominator is "a cause for rethinking your current attitude".

Comment: @Alone-zee yeah it's a good option, albeit limited by context, because **мало ли** unlike **there's no telling** can be used when the speaker is certain about the subject only dismisses its importance

Answer (score 0):

Based on **V.V.**'s examples I believe in all cases **мало ли** anywhere in a sentence bar at the end can be translated as **`there is/could be a lot/different ... so what?`**

> Мало ли какие слухи про нее ходят... - **There is/could be a lot** of gossip/**different** rumors circulating about her, **so what**?
>
> -Ведь она должна была сказать! - But she had to say!
> – Мало ли что должна. -  **There is/could be** a lot she has to do, **so what**?

Translation of **мало ли (что)?** placed at the end of a sentence is more straightforward, because it doesn't imply opposite meaning being just a shorthand of a complete question `мало ли что может случиться?`

> Возьми ружье, мало ли (что)? - Take a rifle, lots of things can happen

Comment: Hi. So what is the precise meaning of "мало"? Should I interpret it as "little/few" or "a lot"? Is it incorrect to translate it as "now matter what/how/etc"?

Comment: @Alone-zee in this construction it means `a lot`, `мало ли` is a form of question `разве мало?` which always implies the opposite, e.g. `разве это он? = он ли это?` *(is this him?)*, `разве я тебе не говорил? = не говорил ли я тебе?` *(didn't i tell you?)*, i agree with @FiatLux's answer

Comment: The plot thickens! Given the presence of the eclipsis at the end, I wonder if you use "мало ли" to convey a sense of **frustration/disappointment** when there are **lots of unpleasant/unwanted** things? And in my example, can I interpret it as: "***(sigh) To think how many groundless rumours are circling around...***"?

Comment: @Alone-zee i don't think there's connotation of **frustration/disappointment** and i don't feel like the speaker is uncertain about the multitude and nature of the rumors, s/he's rather disinterested in them meaning that whatever rumors there're they don't necessarily have to be trusted

Comment: So does "no matter how many ..., it doesn't matter / I don't care" more fit the bill? Or "***regardless of the many rumours***"? Also, I'm not sure if a "мало ли" clause is a subordinate one.

Comment: @Alone-zee indeed '"no matter how many ..., it doesn't matter / I don't care" do fit the bill... in fact both would fit, but the first option is more conservative due to the lack of additional information within the fragment itself, so the preciseness of translation of this particular use case depends on the context, in my 'formal' response i tried to tease out a universal translation